# Implementing different request methods in HTTP Request class

Tags: php, oop, http, httprequest

I'm currently writing my own **HTTP Request** class and I hit a small problem. As you probably know, there are many request methods in PHP, like *OPTIONS*, *GET*, *POST*, *PUT*, *HEAD*, etc. but you cannot mix two or more of them in one request. And this is where my problems begins.

I have HTTPRequest class, which has two static methods, that creates it's instance - **create()**, to create custom HTTP Request and **createFromGlobals()**, to create instance of current request recieved by server.

So, what's the problem? The problem is, I want to find some way to separate request additional functions dependent on method ***(for example, I don't want to have getQueryString() function, when request method is PUT or POST)*** and I want the class to do it for me. Also, I want to keep classes dependencies loose, so whole system will stay flexible.

Do you know any design pattern that resolves problem like mine, or any way to do this?

Comment: It is perfectly valid to do a `POST` request to a uri that also contains a querystring. Same goes for a `PUT` request, I presume, but have never tested this.

Comment: @fireeyedboy, as far as I'm concerned, this works pretty well with FastCGI or NSIS, but there are some problems with Apache (what problems, I'm not sure, so I can't give you any particular examples).

Comment: Well, that's a new one for me; I've never encountered a problem in this regard with Apache. But you could be right.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Symfony Components, it has a very nice Request class (among many other things), so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Comment: Yes, I know Http Foundation quite well, but I'm doing this for practice, to improve my skills.

Comment: Actually re-reading your question, the names of your methods `create` and especially `createFromGlobals` should have given away that you know Symfony Components :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably implement what you want to achieve, similar to this (but keep in mind my comment about querystrings being valid with POST requests. At least, as far as I'm aware):

```
abstract class HTTPRequest
{
    public static function createFromGlobals()
    {
        $method = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ];

        /* initialize additional arguments from globals */

        return self::create( $method /*, additional arguments */ );
    }

    public static function create()
    {
        $arguments = func_get_args();
        $method = array_shift( $arguments );
        $method = ucfirst( strtolower( $method ) );

        $className = __CLASS__ . $method;
        if( !class_exists( $className ) )
        {
            throw new Exception( 'Implementation for method ' . $method . ' not found' );
        }

        $reflector = new ReflectionClass( $className );

        return $reflector->newInstanceArgs( $arguments );
    }

    /* implement common functionality */
}

class HTTPRequestGet
    extends HTTPRequest
{
    /* implement additional GET functionality */
}

class HTTPRequestPost
    extends HTTPRequest
{
    /* implement additional POST functionality */
}

/* etc... */
```

Usage:

```
$requestFromGlobals = HTTPRequest::createFromGlobals();
$customRequest = HTTPRequest::create( 'post', array( 'additional', 'arguments' ) );
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about it too, but I don't like that 'method class' names are strict defined, but there could be no other option.
Eventually I'll make 'method classes' fully separated from Request class. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @SebastianPotasiak But why? What other purpose would those classes serve, other than being HTTP requests? Whatever your reasoning, if you have PHP 5.4, you might consider using [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). It kind of sounds like that is what you are looking for.

Comment: But as far as I'm concerned, traits cannot be used only in certain conditions (I mean, I have no affect whether certain functions are or are not implemented according to request method); they work more like inheritance than like loose coupling, so in this case it doesn't matter if I will use traits or simply implement all required functions in request class.

Answer (score 0):

I was considering something like this:

```
<?php

class HTTPRequest
{
    protected $method;
    public $parameters
    // ...

    public static function create(/* ... */)
    {
        // ...
        switch ($this->method)
        {
            case 'GET':
                $this->parameters = new Parameters($_GET);
                break;
            case 'POST':
                $this->parameters = array(
                    'post' => new Parameters($_POST),
                    'files' => new Parameters($_FILES)
                );
                break;
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

What do you think about it?